# Get the last 4 months of the year in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

i am new to mysql.  I want to know about last 4 month names from sql.

like

```
  SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -level), 'Month') AS month
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 4
```

but how this can be done with mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(curdate(), '%M') month_name
union
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_add(curdate(),interval -1 month), '%M') month_name
union
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_add(curdate(),interval -2 month), '%M') month_name
```

Comment: `cur_date()` is not a mysql function.

Answer (score 4):

probably you can do this:

```
SELECT monthname(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))  union all
SELECT monthname(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)) union all
SELECT monthname(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -3 MONTH)) union all
SELECT monthname(date_add(now(), INTERVAL -4 MONTH))
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3401)

Comment: +1 for simplicity. Also the first time I've seen an accepted answer with negative points - you got robbed :)

Answer (score 2):

@JoeGJoseph's answer is what I would go for, but here is a procedure-based example. This allows you to pass a variable number of months to the procedure and return the previous month names. It isn't pretty, probably won't work correctly and is riddled with errors, but I guess that makes it fun? You can see the fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61ee1/1), and here is the procedure code (note that this may need to be adjusted to work outside of SQLFiddle, but I can't test it anywhere else right now :)):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_months;
CREATE TABLE my_months (month_name VARCHAR(200));

CREATE PROCEDURE LAST_MONTHS(IN num_months INT(10))
BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default -1 ;
      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;
         INSERT INTO my_months VALUES 
             (MONTHNAME(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL-a MONTH)));
         IF a=num_months - 1 THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
END//
```

And then you can call it from your main query like:

```
CALL LAST_MONTHS();
SELECT * FROM my_months;
```

I'd go with the @JoeGJoseph's though, since this is probably overkill and his is more elegant :)

Comment: @JoeGJoseph Ha, thanks - 'working' is one way to put it (I'd say 'completely unnecessary' :) ).